# Version Control of modified linux Operating System

Tags: linux, version-control, operating-system

I customize Linux (RHEL) Operating Systems releases for specific platforms/customers, etc... (and windows).  We do kickstart installs, customize the branding, install specific packages, customize partitioning, etc...

I need suggestions on better ways to version control these OS's.  Currently, we use SVN to Control the base installs (i.e. RHEL 5.6, 6.1, etc...)   We don't upload the base RPMS to the Subversion server as they bloat the repo quick, only custom elements.  We have YUM repos for each of the versions.  A script gets run after checking out the base OS version which then performs a grab from the YUM repo for the specific package versions needed.  I have been unable to find any other posts/guides doing exactly what I need to do.

We basically have to version control the package list for each OS release and do goofy things to get the packages into the base OS to create the final OS image which then gets installed via kickstart (different process for windows).

I find this cumbersome and leads to potential errors.  There must be a better way!  I've looked into an Artifact Repository for the non-modified components but not sure if this will significantly help me.

PS:  Version control for each custom release is critical, I can't even just say RHEL 6.2 is RHEL 6.2, I have to be able to prove the custom release is the correct custom release somehow (as SVN would do).

ANY suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "...can't even just say RHEL 6.2 is RHEL 6.2"? Does it happen due to the modification to the yum repo ?

Comment: I mean that just informing the customers that we "USED" rhel 6.2 isn't good enough.  I have to be able to explicitly show that the version we installed is the same version that we have under configuration management...  In other words, it has to be 100% reproducible.  Example:  we used to store the entire RHEL 5.6 customized image in our SVN repo.  To reproduce the image, we could easily point at the tag associated with our RHEL 5.6 release as SVN managed that.  This solution would have to provide the same level of  confidence in reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Pulp](http://pulpproject.org)? You can create a repository for each "release" that you want to track.

Comment: Never heard of it before.  I will look into this shortly.

Comment: A Quick review of Pulp suggests that it might not be exactly what I need for this effort, but may help me in others.  I already have a couple of YUM Repos mirroring the OEM OS.  I need something that will performing some type of version management for each package group (maybe pulp does this?) --- I figured SOMEONE out there has done something like this before to create, manage, and control customized operating systems with full Configuration Management practices.

Comment: ahhh... after thinking about it a bit more, at the least, Pulp might be able to work to a limited extent by doing as you suggested--creating a repo for each OS release.  It at least seems to simplify the repo management process a bit.  I currently had yum repos for each release.  (quite the pain to manage).  I might have to give this a go.  I still think there must be a more comprehensive solution that covers all of my issues (why I was thinking of using [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)